# C vs python for a simple word list generator

Tags: python, c, algorithm, performance, python-3.x

I wrote a word-list generator originally in C some while ago, which took about 2 days. I used a dedicated int array to store the indices and incremented them using the idea of number bases. Here is my source code:

```
/*
 * Generates word lists from a character set
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int power(int x, int y);
void ntoarray(int n, int base, int seq[], int len);
void setchar(char charset[], char word[], int indices[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // checks arguments
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s start_length end_length charset", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // loops from start length to end length
        for (int lenword = atoi(argv[1]), lim = atoi(argv[2]); lenword <= lim; lenword++)
        {
            // pointer to character set
            char *charset = argv[3];
            // length of the character set
            int lencharset = strlen(charset);
            // array for the word
            char word[lenword + 1];
            word[lenword] = '\0';
            // array for storing the indices to generate the word from the character set
            int indices[lenword];
            // number to convert to required base
            int n = 0;
            // repetition is allowed so the number of times to loop is number^choice
            for (int i = 0; i < power(lencharset, lenword); i++)
            {
                // converts number to an integer array with length of the charset as the base
                ntoarray(n++, lencharset, indices, lenword);
                // sets the word according to the indices array
                setchar(charset, word, indices);
                // prints the word
                printf("%s\n", word);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

// simple power algorithm which raises x to the power y
int power(int x, int y)
{
    int n = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        n *= x;
    return n;
}

// converts n to the required base and stores it in an integer array
void ntoarray(int n, int base, int seq[], int len)
{
    int i = len - 1;
    memset(seq, 0, sizeof(int) * len);
    while (i >= 0 && n >= base)
    {
        int r = n % base;
        n /= base;
        seq[i--] = r;
    }
    seq[i] = n;
}

// sets the word by combining the data from the indices array and the charset array
void setchar(char charset[], char word[], int indices[])
{
    int len = strlen(word);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        word[i] = charset[indices[i]];
    }
}
```

Now I have rewritten it in python3 using a similar idea, but it took only about an hour.

```
"""
    Generates word lists from a character set.
"""

import argparse

def main():
    # checks arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("start_length", help = "starting length for your words", type = int)
    parser.add_argument("end_length", help = "ending length for your words", type = int)
    parser.add_argument("charset", help = "character set to be used", type = str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    charset = args.charset
    len_charset = len(charset)
    # loops from start_length to end_length
    for length in range(args.start_length, args.end_length + 1):
        # initializes indices list
        indices = [0] * length
        # prints the word
        print(genword(charset, indices))
        # increments the indices list and prints the word until the limit
        # repetition is allowed so the number of loops is base ^ length - 1 (-1 for the printed word)
        for i in range(len_charset ** length - 1):
            inc_seq(indices, len_charset)
            print(genword(charset, indices))

def inc_seq(seq, base, index=-1):
    """
        Increments a number sequence with a specified base by one.
    """
    if seq[index] < base - 1:
        seq[index] += 1
    else:
        inc_seq(seq, base, index - 1)
        seq[index] = 0

def genword(charset, indices):
    """
        Generates a word by combining a character set and a list of indices.
    """
    return "".join([charset[i] for i in indices])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

There is a notable difference: In C, I incremented an intermediary number n and used it to modify the int array; in python, I harnessed the power of negative indices to directly increment the int list.

I learned to code mostly by self-study (i.e. reading books and using online resources), but I do not yet know how to analyze algorithms properly. So my question is: Which version is more efficient, in terms of time and space?

Comment: Huh? I haven't looked closely at your code, but generally C will be much faster than Python because C gets compiled to machine code that the the CPU can execute directly, whereas Python gets compiled to bytecode that runs on a virtual machine. C works with the CPU's native datatypes, whereas everything in Python is an object and those objects occupy much more RAM than native datatypes. So Python is slower & uses more RAM. But as you've noticed it's generally _much_ faster to write & to debug Python than C.

Comment: Looks like: "I have no driving licence and no practice in driving. Normally, I go to work by bus, that takes me half an hour. Today I used a rental car, that took me two hours. What's wrong?"

Comment: This should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you do is: `from itertools import chain, product; chain.from_iterable(product(charset, repeat=r) for r in range(start_length, end_length + 1))`. Right?

Comment: Search for the keyword "profiling" with respect to C and python to find tools which will help you evaluate the performance and resource impact of your programs.

Comment: You re-compute power(x,y) for every word in the c++ code. It also looks like ntoarray is O(word_length), but inc_ind looks to be average O(1) because it keeps the previous state instead of recomputing it. I'm just eyeballing it though. A profiler would tell you if you are spending a large amount of time in those functions.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you. In particular, I would like to know how python lists compare to C arrays.

Comment: @KennyOstrom The points you made are very helpful. I used `for (int i = 0, n = power(lencharset, lenword); i < n; i++)` and made a C version of `inc_seq` by using `lenword - 1` for the -1 index in python, but C does not throw an index-out-of-range error, so I had to put some error checking to prevent it messing up with other memory. Now hopefully I have optimized my incrementing algorithm from O(n) to O(1). Thank you very much.

Comment: If you _really_ want to understand how Python lists work you should take a look at the CPython source code, [listobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c). It's commented quite well, and you can learn a lot just by looking at that file, although I guess it's helpful to refer to the Python.h header file too. The Python list object is implemented as a C structure that stores pointers to the list items in an array member called `ob_item`.